# Correct type annotation for a peekable iterator from more-itertools?

Tags: python, python-itertools, python-typing, more-itertools

This code doesn't type-check:

```py
def parse_expression(lex: Iterator[Token]) -> Expression:
    left = parse_term(lex)
    if lex.peek(): # ERROR
        # ...
```

The error message is `Cannot access member "peek" for type "Iterator[Token]"`, which is probably expected.

The argument I want to pass to this method is `more_itertools.peekable(lex(src))`. `lex` returns an `Iterable[Token]` (yields `Token`s).

What type annotation should I use?

Comment: Accept `more_itertools.peekable[Token]`? According to source code, it's [a class](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/more.pyi#L60), and the whole package is typed. What is your actual problem?..

Comment: @SUTerliakov oh man I feel so stupid I didn't import it haha